# how to get a item inside item in html angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried get a value from both dynamic objects in angular js

```
<div ng-controller="SampleController">
<div> {{item['111']['price']}}
</div>
```

inside SampleController

```
$scope.item={111:{price:"232"},112:{price:"233"},115:{price:"237"}};
```

right now I put item['111']['price'] statically. if when i receive the value dynamically from some where else how to that.
Like,

```
<div ng-controller="SampleController">
<div> {{item[{{ItemId['id']}}]['price']}}
</div>

$scope.ItemId={id:111};
$scope.item={111:{price:"232"},112:{price:"233"},115:{price:"237"}};
```

But its returning error. I tried with route scope also.Any one please help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div>{{item[ItemId.id].price}}</div>
```

Comment: If i have ng-click = sendTo({{item[ItemId.id].price}});How can i pass the price as parameter in that ?

Comment: Yes you can. But no need for curly braces. Just `ng-click="sendTo(item[ItemId.id].price)"` is enough.